# Let $S=\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R} \mid x>0\rbrace$ for each $x\in S$ define $A_x=(\frac{-1}{x},\frac{1}{x})$.Find $\bigcap_{x\in S}A_{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

> Let $S=\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R} \mid x>0\rbrace$ for each $x\in S$ define  $A_x=(\frac{-1}{x},\frac{1}{x})$.Find $\bigcap_{x\in S}A_{x}$

**Attempt**

For every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x>0$ then $\frac{-1}{x}<0<\frac{1}{x}$ therefore is natural think that $\bigcap_{x\in S}A_{x}=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Now assume that exists $\mathcal{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha\in \bigcap_{x\in S}A_{x}$, $\alpha \neq 0$.

By our assumption  $\frac{-1}{x}<\alpha<\frac{1}{x}$for all $x\in S$ if $\alpha>0$ then by Arquimedian property of reals numbers there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\alpha$ a contradiction with the hypotetesis that $\alpha<\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\in S$.

Assume that $ \alpha<0$ then $-\alpha>0$ and therefore there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<-\alpha$ it is $\alpha<\frac{-1}{n}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$,which is a contradiction with the hypotesis that $\frac{-1}{x}<\alpha$ for all $x\in S$

therefore the result is true as well.

Any suggestion or gramatic correction was helpful, I´m Not native speaker

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank so much, I really appreciate your opinion